# Video on Amazon Cloudfront CDN does not play in Firefox mediaelement.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, firefox, video, cdn, mediaelement.js

Using W3 Total Cache, I have just distributed a video on the Amazon Cloudfront CDN and have been testing it with mediaelement.js. It is working well on Windows 7 (Chrome and IE9) and Windows XP Pro (Chrome and IE8). But, it does not play in Firefox ver 16.01 on either Windows 7 or Windows XP. On Win 7 / Firefox, I see the poster and controls, click play and it tries to play showing the dotted download circle, but does not complete. On Win XP / Firefox, I only see a black rectangle - no controls or anything.

Firefox does work in Win 7 if I play the video from the origin server where mediaelement.js is installed, i.e. not from Amazon Cloudfront CDN. It still has issues in Win XP - it plays the video but the controls cannot be activated by the mouse. So, it plays once then stops and cannot be played again.

So this appears to be an issue with Firefox and the Amazon Cloudfront CDN. Does anyone know why Firefox does not like playing the video from the Amazon Cloudfront CDN?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your video. Firefox doesn't support mp4 if this is your only format. Convert the video in webm also and add it to your in same way as the mp4 file.